How to decrease solder mask clearance of footprint in Kicad 8.0?
I'm getting an error in Kicad because the soldermask aperture is bridging with itself internally within a footprint. It looks like this:


I'm wondering how I can decrease the soldermask border so I can stop getting this error.


You can get help from this Q and A. https://forum.kicad.info/t/how-to-reduce-the-clearance-between-pads-and-solder-mask/16349
